# Map texture to a circle

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, texture-mapping

Im trying to add a texture to a circle that I currently have created using a Triangle Fan. The image of the circle is below. It is missing one triangle, not sure why. Besides that I have a texture I wish to map to the circle ontop of the color of the circle.

Here is where I draw the "Balls":

```
-(void)drawBall:(ImageTextures *) textures;
{

float angle, radian, x, y;
float radius = self.diameter/2;

[textures bindTextureAt:0];

GLfloat vertexBuffer[362];
vertexBuffer[0] = self.x_Pos;
vertexBuffer[1] = self.y_Pos;
int count = 2;

for (angle = 0.0; angle <= 362.0; angle += 2.0) {
    radian = angle * (3.14/180.0f);

    float xcos = (float)cos(radian);
    float ysin = (float)sin(radian);
    x = xcos * radius  + self.x_Pos;
    y = ysin * radius  + self.y_Pos;

    vertexBuffer[count] = x;
    count = count + 1;
    vertexBuffer[count] = y;
    count = count + 1;
}

count = 0;


glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 180);

glColor4f(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, 0.1f);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

Here is where I actually load the texture:

```
- (void)loadTextureAt : (int) at from:(NSString *)file {
CGImageRef texImage = [UIImage imageNamed:file].CGImage;
if ( ! texImage ) {
    NSLog(@"Texture file not found!");
    return;
}

int texWidth = (int)CGImageGetWidth(texImage);
int texHeight = (int)CGImageGetHeight(texImage);

GLubyte *texData = (GLubyte*)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);

CGContextRef texContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(texData, texWidth, texHeight, 8, texWidth*4,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(texImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGContextDrawImage(texContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)texWidth, (float)texHeight), texImage);
CGContextRelease(texContext);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureIDs[at]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texData);

free(texData);
}
```

Then I call bind the texture with:

```
- (void)bindTextureAt : (int) at {
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureIDs[at]);
};
```

This is where I call draw ball to draw all the balls on the screen:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

for (int i = 0; i < [self.balls count]; i++) {
    [self.balls[i] drawBall: _textures];

}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated Here is the image of the ball right now and the texture that I want to map to the ball.

[image: Ball Missing one triangle][image: The texture]

Comment: If you change the last parameter to `glDrawArrays()` to be 181 instead of 180, does it draw the whole circle?

Comment: thanks, i managed to get that part. Now the texture still wont load

Comment: Where are your texture coordinates and all the code that goes with textures when drawing the circle. Also a common issue is not using a power of two texture dimensions.

Comment: Worth noting: there probably isn’t a reason to use a triangle

Comment: The texture Im using is 64 x 64 so that shouldn't be the problem. The first bit of code is where Im creating the points where I want the triangles to be drawn in the fan. And that is where I bind the texture .

Comment: You need to complete the circle.  `for (angle = 0.0; angle <= 360.0 angle += 2.0) {`